# Android bitmaps, recycling, and heap fragmentation

Tags: android

I have an app that makes heavy use of bitmaps read in from the SD card. I'm 99% sure my app is never destroyed without recycling these. They are all allocated into an LRU cache (commons-collections) which recycles them as they are purged from the LRU cache, and I recycle the remaining in `onDestroy()`.

Nonetheless, I still have problems. If I start / stop / start / ... my app several times, I get out of memory error, always.

My theory on this is that it has to do with Android's non-compacting heap. After several runs, the heap is sufficiently fragmented so although there is plenty of free memory, there's no contiguous chunks big enough to load the bitmaps. That's the theory anyway.

I've been "solving" this by killing my process in `onDestroy()` (`android.os.Process.killProcess()`). This solves the problem, but introduces other issues of its own as I have other threads and services that need to complete, and waiting for all of those nicely is not practical. Not to mention that I of course understand that this is just a really bad practice.

I've read all the posts, etc on this topic and I don't see a good solution. I'm using `Thumbnails.getThumbnail()`, so I'm already using scaled down versions of the images. Subsampling them further results in very poor image quality.

I'm keeping a cache of 8 "mini" thumbnails and 36 "micro" thumbnails, so I never have any more than that in memory at a time. These should all fit in a few megs at very most.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you recycle them in `onDestroy()`, but perhaps you should recycle them in `onPause()`? I've run into some out of memory issues when switching orientation and the issue was solved by doing recycling in `onPause()`.

Just a thought. Not sure if that'll solve your issue.

Comment: thanks, this didn't solve the problem but it seems like good practice. i'd assumed that it would cause problems with other objects that are still referencing the bitmaps, bit it does not seem to do so.